# UITableView/indexPath.row: why does if statement exclude row 10?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As a learner I was just playing around with `UITableView`, custom `UITableViewCell`, `reloadData()` and all to get to know these things.

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` with two `UILabels`. The first one is supposed to hold a running number (`indexPath.row`) and the second one should hold user entered content. All good - worked fine. Then I thought it might work in only one `UILabel`, too, by constructing a string from both - row number and content. While testing a few `if` statements to align the cells nicely I came along this:

I have this code in the `cellForRowAt` function:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 4 || indexPath.row == 5 || indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 7 || indexPath.row == 8 || indexPath.row == 9 {

     cell.textLabel?.text = "0\(indexPath.row + 1). \(userContent[indexPath.row])"

 } else if indexPath.row == 10 || indexPath.row == 11 || indexPath.row == 12 || indexPath.row == 13 || indexPath.row == 14 || indexPath.row == 15 || indexPath.row == 16 {

     cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(userContent[indexPath.row])"

        }
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Entry 10 has a leading 0 although I told it not to have]

As I said: I was just playing around and this happened just by accident. Did I miss anything here?

I just want to understand why row 10 doesn't *respect* the if statement.
Thanks a lot for any explanation.

Comment: Nooooo! See my comment under matt‘s answer. I thank you very much but you have destroyed my research evening haha ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't read the comments. Will delete the traces.

Comment: Oh... eh... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walk thru your code, while thinking "what if this is row 0", then "what if this is row 1", and so forth:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 1 || 
   indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 || 
   indexPath.row == 4 || indexPath.row == 5 || 
   indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 7 || 
   indexPath.row == 8 || indexPath.row == 9 {
       cell.textLabel?.text = 
           "0\(indexPath.row + 1). \(userContent[indexPath.row])"
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now assume this is row 9. `indexPath.row` is 9, so we take this branch. We add 1, get 10, put a `0` in front of it, and print `010`.

This is a typical "edge case" or "off-by-one" beginner error (also routinely made by nonbeginners, so don't feel bad).

Comment: Holy... thanks, @matt. This was just too obvious to see it seems. When I delete that "+1" if works. But first row starts with 0 then :D

Comment: Oh, your entire code needs rewriting. But you didn't ask how to rewrite it; you just asked what was causing the output. And, I think, rightly so; thinking about the rewrite, which can be vastly simpler and more elegant, is left as an exercise for you! (Hint: you added 1 in the wrong place.) (Another Hint: the concept "is between 0 and 9" is much easier to express than what you are saying.)

Comment: No, don't say how. All fine here. I will get there :D

Comment: :) No problem, I wouldn't want to ruin the fun!

Comment: Love the explanation! +1

Answer (score 0):

You also can use switch to clean your code

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0..<10:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "0\(indexPath.row)"
    default: 
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

}
```